# Seaborn barplot with 2 bars with the same label

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, seaborn

I am using seaborn with python3 to create a horizontal barplot, like so:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

if __name__ == '__main__':

    names  = ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Bob']
    values = [3, 2, 1]

    sns.barplot(x = values, y = names)

    plt.savefig('seaborn_figure.png')
```

Sometimes, two bars will have the same label (as in the example above), which leads seaborn to draw the two datapoints with that label as one bar with an extra error bar:

[image: seaborn barplot]

I would prefer seaborn not to combine the values (i.e. this particular chart should have three horizontal columns, with two of them labeled Bob).

I've tried setting `xerr = None` in the `sns.barplot()` call, but it changes nothing.

It would be better if I did not have the label duplication, but unfortunately the names are set by people outside of my sphere of influence. I could of course get around this by renaming the datapoints (e.g. "Bob 1" and "Bob 2"), but that is not an elegant solution.

Is there a way to force seaborn to draw as many bars as there are labels/values, even if some labels are identical?

Comment: I once solved something like this by appending the 'INVISIBLE SEPARATOR' unicode character `u"\u2063"`.

Comment: I honestly think you should try to avoid using the same name for the bars. This goes against all sensible directions for data visualization. How would you even be able to tell which one is which? Would it really make sense?

Comment: @SergeyAntopolskiy I agree completely. Unfortunately (as I said in the question), I do not actually set the names - they are set by people far away from me. Interestingly, in plain matplotlib, similar code produces the desired result. This behavior is seaborn-specific.

Comment: @StaringFrog, ok, if you agree, the best way would be to come up with an the elegant way to rename the groups. In any case, it is much better to always shape your data before you visualize it. You must have full control over it. On a side note: perhaps you don't actually want the barplot? (barplots are actually quite lame; there is a common rule of thump among data scientists: "if you want to use barplot, you don't want to use barplot"). Maybe what you actually want is a strip-plot in which data points with the same name would be shown as points, but clustered together?

Comment: As a follow-up to this question... I ended up doing exactly what Sergey suggests: adding clarification to the duplicate names. In the simple example from my question, I would make the conflicting names "Bob 1" and "Bob 2", for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You *can* do this with something like the following:

```
names  = ['a', 'b', 'c']
values = [3, 2, 1]

ax = sns.barplot(x = values, y = names)
ax.set_yticklabels(['Alice', 'Bob', 'Bob'])
```

But *should* you do this? It doesn't really make sense for seaborn to do what you are asking, so you may be better off just importing `seaborn` to get the style you want, but then plotting with `matplotlib` so you can plot exactly what you want.